# Retrieve an audio clip from firebase and use Google Cloud, Speech to text api. to retrieve the transcription of that clip

Tags: java, android, firebase

I've uploaded a short voice clip to firebase and would like to convert that to text using the 'Cloud speech to text api' and display the text on a device and send the voice clip? Working in android studio.

So to be clear, retrieve the audio and a transcription of the audio file? How can I do this? Thanks.

I have already tried to use the speech to text api a long with a media recorder, however they don't work simultaneously and only the file saves.

Comment: Hi Namenots, I am also trying to solve the same problem.
Have you found any solution yet?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. I couldn't find a way of doing this. At the moment it seems that only web apps can do this and google currently, does not support the conversion of an audio file to text on android.